# Page Auto maximize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoresize

So, this code is for auto maximizing page when it is loading BUT it was working before firefox update, NOW it is working fine in IE but it does not do anything in FF anymore... any suggestions how to fix it, or if you have some working script it will be great!

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

top.window.moveTo(0,0);
if (document.all) {
top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
}
else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
if (top.window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight||top.window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth){
top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new "fix" in the latest update. See here:

[Bug 565541 - Web sites shouldn't be allowed to resize main window](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541)

It prevents web pages running code to resize the window. There have already been a lot of complaints that this disables a useful feature.